# Has Microsoft published symbol files for Microsoft Edge?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

I am working on a browsing accessibility plugin and I want to make it compatible with Edge. I started working on its compatibility with Edge's latest Insiders build (#10122) and I have a few issues that I am trying to debug. Unfortunately, I didn't find symbols files for this build of Edge.

Did Microsoft publish symbols for Edge? If so, where can I download them?

Comment: By "symbol files" do you mean the .pdb link between .exe and .dll files?

Comment: Yep, exactly.Specifically, It seems that I need spframe.dll's pdb.

Comment: Symbols are usually available via their public symbol server.

Comment: I also assumed that the relevant symbols will be published on Microsoft's symbol server (http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols) shortly after the release of the preview versions.
But it seems that it's not the case for Windows 10 or at least Spartan (Edge).

Is there exist a dedicated server for Win 10 symbols stuff?